# discrepancy calculating power of 1 sided 1 sample proportion test

Tags: r, proportion, statistical-power

I am running the R code below to compare two methods for finding the power for a one-sided (greater) test of a proportion versus a fixed value ie lower bound (ie one sample test) - I have sample size 87, the lower bound is 0.8 and the assumed true value is 0.9

The first way is "home made" - I find the lower confidence interval (wilson in this case) of all possible outcome from 0 out of 87 to 87 out of 87. I calculate which of the lower CIs are greater than the lower bound. I then multiply the resulting logical vector that has Fs and Ts (T for when the lower bound is exceeded by the power CIs of the events 0,1,..., 87 out of 87) by the actual probabilities of 0,1,..., 87 out of 87 using dbinom. I sum this to get the total probability of the event where the lower CI when prob=p exceeds the lower bound aka the power.
I then try and confirm my code using the pwr.p.test from the pwr package in R and get a different estimate of power : my one-liner=74.9% pwr.p.test=84.2%
Why is this ? I get similar answers in the one-liner for several CI options (eg exact or wilson). How does pwr.p.test work ? I see a reference to arcsin ? I might expect small differences but there are quite large differences even for large values of n. Am I using pow.p.test wrong - are my alphas agreeing (should it be hald alpha somewhere ??) Is there just a silly mistake ??? many thanks for advice

```
library(pwr)
library(binom)
n<-87
lb<-0.8
p<-0.9
sum((binom.confint(0:n, n, alpha=0.05, method=c("wilson"))$lower>lb)*dbinom(0:n,n,p)  )
pwr.p.test(h = ES.h(p1 = p, p2 = lb),
           sig.level = 0.05,
           n=n,
           alternative = "greater")
```

Comment: It's a rather silly mistake :-) The confidence interval in your function is two-sided, while `pwr.p.test()` with `alternative="greater"` is one-sided. Further, the option in `binom.confint()` to specify the alpha is called `conf.level` not `alpha` (at least in my version of the package, which I just downloaded).

Comment: thank you, LuckyPal, you are a star ... so it I change code to this it agrees - now I wonder if  1 sided 2.5% or 5% is best

Comment: ```
sum((binom.confint(0:n, n, conf.level=0.9, method=c("wilson"))$lower>lb)*dbinom(0:n,n,p)  )
pwr.p.test(h = ES.h(p1 = p, p2 = lb),
           sig.level = 0.05,
           n=n,
           alternative = "greater")
```